# Download files in network tab in inspection

Tags: google-chrome, imagedownload, google-developer-tools

I'm trying to find a way to automatically download all files (normally more than 60 files) in the network tab. Is there any software, extensions, bots, or something that is capable of downloading all these files or just images?

Description image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe [IDM](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/download.html) does this, its free and there is also paid version.

Answer (score 0):

*** Disclaimer: Answer by HttpWatch Developer ***

Our HttpWatch software (Windows only) that works with Chrome and Edge can help you do this. Its programmatic interface (see https://apihelp.httpwatch.com) could be used to record access to a web page or set of URLs and then export the corresponding files using the [Export method](https://apihelp.httpwatch.com/HttpWatch_API%7EHttpWatch.Content%7EExport.html?highlight=export%2C).